# How to assign dynamic url value to flutter video player using getx and update ui

Tags: flutter, dart

I am working on an app that uses flutter_video_player package. Here is my  Video player controller class

```
           class VPlayerController extends GetxController {
           late VideoPlayerController videoPlayerController;
           ChewieController? chewieController;
                 @override
               void onInit() {
               initPlayer();
               super.onInit();
               }



         void initPlayer() async {
        // i want to make url dynamic
         videoPlayerController = 
         VideoPlayerController.network('http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv- 
          videos-bucket/sample/ElephantsDream.mp4');
           await videoPlayerController.initialize().then((value) {
           chewieController =
            ChewieController(videoPlayerController: videoPlayerController);
          }).catchError((e) {
             Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: e);
             });

        chewieController = ChewieController(
         videoPlayerController: videoPlayerController,
          autoPlay: false,
           looping: true,
          showControls: true,
            errorBuilder: (context, errorMessage) {
              return Center(
                child: Text(
                     errorMessage,
                    ),
                  );
                 },
                autoInitialize: true,
                materialProgressColors: ChewieProgressColors(
                bufferedColor: primary.withOpacity(0.5),
                backgroundColor: primary.withOpacity(0.5),
                handleColor: primary,
                playedColor: primary),
                cupertinoProgressColors: ChewieProgressColors(),
               );
          }

     @override
     void onClose() {
       videoPlayerController.dispose();
          chewieController!.dispose();
          super.onClose();
          }
         }
```

This is my main screen to display. It does not show video player not untill i do a hot reload and i would like to assign the video url directly from this screen not in my controller. How to achieve this?

```
                 class TopicView extends StatelessWidget {
               // i want to pass thus url to the video player
                 final String? url;
                  const TopicView({super.key, this.url});




        @override
         Widget build(BuildContext context) {
         return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(title: Text(widget.courseId)),
           body: SizedBox(
             width: ScreenManager.getWidth(context),
              height: ScreenManager.getHeight(context),
                child: Padding(
                 padding: const EdgeInsets.all(AppPadding.p16),
                  child: Column(
                  children: [
                    // i want to pass the video url dynamically here
                        GetBuilder<VPlayerController>(
                         init: VPlayerController(),
                         builder: (controller) {
                          return Expanded(
                              child: controller.chewieController != null &&
                                 controller.chewieController!
                                .videoPlayerController.value.isInitialized
                                  ? Chewie(controller: controller.chewieController!)
                                 : const Text('no data'));
                                 }),
        
                              ],
                             ),
                             ),
                             ),
                            );

                          }
                   }
```

Answer (score 0):

well of course it won't work because the url/variables have to be in the controller then call it to the video player, if you place the url in the screen just `setState` to update the screen.